# Histogram matching - image processing - c/c++

Tags: math, statistics, probability, histogram

I have two histograms.

```
int Hist1[10] = {1,4,3,5,2,5,4,6,3,2};

int Hist1[10] = {1,4,3,15,12,15,4,6,3,2};
```

Hist1's distribution is of type multi-modal;

Hist2's distribution is of type uni-modal with single prominent peak.

My questions are

1. Is there any way that i could determine the type of distribution programmatically?
2. How to quantify whether these two histograms are similar/dissimilar?

Thanks

Comment: You may find this question helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661402/r-given-a-set-of-random-numbers-drawn-from-a-continuous-univariate-distribution .  The answers, however, refer to the R programming environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raj,

I posted a C function in your other question ( [automatically compare two series -Dissimilarity test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986536/automatically-compare-two-series-dissimilarity-test) ) that will compute divergence between two sets of similar data.  It's actually intended to tell you how closely real data matches predicted data but I suspect you could use it for your purpose.

Basically, the smaller the error, the more similar the two sets are.

Answer (score 1):

These are just guesses, but I would try fitting each distribution as a gaussian distribution and use something like the R-squared value to determine if the distribution is uni-modal or not.

As to the similarity between the two distributions, I would try doing an [autocorrelation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) and using the peak positive value in the autocorrelation as a similarity measure. These ideas are pretty rough, but hopefully they give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

For #2, you could calculate their [cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) (so long as the buckets themselves can be sorted). That would give you a rough estimation of what "similarity".

Answer (score 0):

[Comparison of Histograms](http://mtsu32.mtsu.edu:11235/Activities/nasafinalreport.doc) (For Use in Cloud Modeling).

(That's an MS .doc file.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of software packages that will "fit" your distributions to known discrete distributions for you - Minitab, STATA, R, etc.  A reference to fitting distributions in [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) is [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf).  I wouldn't advise programming this from scratch.

Regarding distribution comparisons, if neither distribution fits a known distribution (Poisson, Binomial, etc.), then you need to use non-parametric methods described [here](http://www.texasoft.com/winkmann.html).