# How do I fit distributions to sample data in R?

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I've been struggling with fitting a distribution to sample data I have in R. I've looked at using the fitdist as well as fitdistr functions, but I seem to be running into problems with both.

A quick background; the output of my code should be the most fitting distribution (from a list of distributions) to the data provided, with parameters. This needs to happen without human interaction, so comparing graphs is not an option. I was thinking that I could fit each distribution to the data, draw the p-value from the chi-squared test and find the distribution with the highest p-value. I've gotten some success in a normal distribution to the sample data, but as soon as I try to fit something more complex (a gamma distribution, as seen in the code), I get all kinds of errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(fitdistrplus) 
require(MASS) 
set.seed(1) 
testData <- rnorm(1000) 
distlist <- c("norm","unif","exp")

(z <- fitdist(testData,"gamma",start=list(rate=0.1),fix.arg=list(shape=4)))
```

Examples of errors I get are:

> [1] "Error in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs =
>   data,  : \n  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite\n" attr(,"class")

and

> Error in fitdist(testData, "gamma", start = list(rate = 0.1), fix.arg
>   = list(shape = 4)) :    the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
>                   with the error code 100

I know I'm probably implementing the fitdist function incorrectly, but I can't seem to find simple examples I can adapt to achieve my code objectives. Can anyone help?

Comment: the error message says it all: the loglikelihood is not finite at the initial value. The gamma distribution has positive support while the sample certainly has negative values, thus the loglikelihood is infinite.

Comment: Hm. Never even considered this; you are right. I'll try to put in some controls on the sample data to only include positive data. Thanks for the feedback, man.

Comment: closely related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30491/automatically-determine-probability-distribution-given-a-data-set , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661402/given-a-set-of-random-numbers-drawn-from-a-continuous-univariate-distribution-f

Comment: Additionally, I wouldn't recommend to use p-values for model selection, they do not express the probability that the observations are generated by a particular model. [Akaike information criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) would be a simple, easy to calculate alternative.

Comment: @Arpi, thank you very much for the suggestion. I'll read up on the technique and see if it works better. Any help or suggestions are highly valued, so I really appreciate this.

Comment: @Ben-Bolker thanks very much for the links; it was tricky finding relevant articles on what I wanted to do!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. Null hypothesis is that the data sample is from the hypothesised distribution.

```
fitData <- function(data, fit="gamma", sample=0.5){
 distrib = list()
 numfit <- length(fit)
 results = matrix(0, ncol=5, nrow=numfit)

 for(i in 1:numfit){
if((fit[i] == "gamma") | 
     (fit[i] == "poisson") | 
     (fit[i] == "weibull") | 
     (fit[i] == "exponential") |
     (fit[i] == "logistic") |
     (fit[i] == "normal") | 
     (fit[i] == "geometric")
) 
  distrib[[i]] = fit[i]
else stop("Provide a valid distribution to fit data" )
 }

 # take a sample of dataset
 n = round(length(data)*sample)
 data = sample(data, size=n, replace=F)

 for(i in 1:numfit) {
  if(distrib[[i]] == "gamma") {
  gf_shape = "gamma"
  fd_g <- fitdistr(data, "gamma")
  est_shape = fd_g$estimate[[1]]
  est_rate = fd_g$estimate[[2]]

  ks = ks.test(data, "pgamma", shape=est_shape, rate=est_rate)

  # add to results
  results[i,] = c(gf_shape, est_shape, est_rate, ks$statistic, ks$p.value)
}

else if(distrib[[i]] == "poisson"){
  gf_shape = "poisson"
  fd_p <- fitdistr(data, "poisson")
  est_lambda = fd_p$estimate[[1]]

  ks = ks.test(data, "ppois", lambda=est_lambda)
  # add to results
  results[i,] = c(gf_shape, est_lambda, "NA", ks$statistic, ks$p.value)
}

else if(distrib[[i]] == "weibull"){
  gf_shape = "weibull"
  fd_w <- fitdistr(data,densfun=dweibull,start=list(scale=1,shape=2))
  est_shape = fd_w$estimate[[1]]
  est_scale = fd_w$estimate[[2]]

  ks = ks.test(data, "pweibull", shape=est_shape, scale=est_scale)
  # add to results
  results[i,] = c(gf_shape, est_shape, est_scale, ks$statistic, ks$p.value) 
}

else if(distrib[[i]] == "normal"){
  gf_shape = "normal"
  fd_n <- fitdistr(data, "normal")
  est_mean = fd_n$estimate[[1]]
  est_sd = fd_n$estimate[[2]]

  ks = ks.test(data, "pnorm", mean=est_mean, sd=est_sd)
  # add to results
  results[i,] = c(gf_shape, est_mean, est_sd, ks$statistic, ks$p.value)
}

else if(distrib[[i]] == "exponential"){
  gf_shape = "exponential"
  fd_e <- fitdistr(data, "exponential")
  est_rate = fd_e$estimate[[1]]
  ks = ks.test(data, "pexp", rate=est_rate)
  # add to results
  results[i,] = c(gf_shape, est_rate, "NA", ks$statistic, ks$p.value)
}

else if(distrib[[i]] == "logistic"){
  gf_shape = "logistic"
  fd_l <- fitdistr(data, "logistic")
  est_location = fd_l$estimate[[1]]
  est_scale = fd_l$estimate[[2]]
  ks = ks.test(data, "plogis", location=est_location, scale=est_scale)
  # add to results
  results[i,] = c(gf_shape, est_location, est_scale, ks$statistic,    ks$p.value) 
    }
  }
  results = rbind(c("distribution", "param1", "param2", "ks stat", "ks    pvalue"),   results)
  #print(results)
  return(results)
  }
```

Applied to your example:

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(1) 
testData <- rnorm(1000) 
res = fitData(testData, fit=c("logistic","normal","exponential","poisson"),
    sample=1)
res
```

You do not reject the null hypothesis for the Normal.

Reference: https://web.archive.org/web/20150407031710/http://worldofpiggy.com:80/2014/02/25/automatic-distribution-fitting-r/

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you so much for this, it explains exactly what I need. I assume I can expand this function to include other distributions as well? Apologies if my question sounds stupid, my knowledge of R is still growing.

Comment: Yes, you can extend it to other distributions, but your knowledge about the nature of the data should limit your options to a few distributions.

Comment: KS test is inappropriate for fitted distributions, i.e. where the parameters of the distribution are estimated from the data. In such cases the KS statistic is no lodger distribution-free and the critical values are inaccurate. There are some techniques to modify the statistic in such a way that it does become distribution-free even cases where parameters are estimated, but it is non-trivial (see, for example, [Khmaladze Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khmaladze_transformation)).

Comment: The p-values of a Kolmovorov-Smirnov-Test (KS-Test) with estimated parameters will be quite wrong. So unfortunately, you can't just fit a distribution and then use the estimated parameters in a Kolmogorov-Smirnov-Test to test your sample. Look at this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/how-to-determine-which-distribution-fits-my-data-best

Answer (score 1):

I consider the error is mainly because of your data. As seen in the error message, `NaN` is created so that the function seems to fail to obtain the score (by differentiating the density function). [range of density function is non-negative, isn't?]

[Method of moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_%28statistics%29), which is simpler, is used instead of maximum likelihood estimation and it produces parameter estimates in spite of a warning.

```
library(fitdistrplus) 
require(MASS) 
set.seed(1) 
testData <- rnorm(1000) 
fitdist(testData, "gamma", method = "mme", start = list(shape = 0.1, rate = 0.1))

Fitting of the distribution ' gamma ' by matching moments 
Parameters:
           estimate
shape  0.0001268054
rate  -0.0108863200
Warning message:
In dgamma(c(-0.626453810742332, 0.183643324222082, -0.835628612410047,  :
  NaNs produced
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I actually never considered using MME, which is the superior fit for this problem as you noted. I assume I can simply draw the chi-squared p-value from this using something like gofstat?

Comment: MME just uses moments to fit distribution while MLE uses more information by fitting likelihood function and, I guess, it is why the former at least returns an outcome. | The domain of the gamma distribution is [0, infinity) while it is (-infinity, infinity) for the normal distribution so that negative realizations of the random sample would cause a problem. Therefore, if values are strictly controlled, I guess `fitdist()` should return an outcome. | The second way may also be used as a way of non-parametric estimation.